# Nested list in PairedBarChart

Tags: plotting

I have a dataset consisting of 2 different parameters (`x` and `y`), that are evaluated for 3 different values of parameter `p` and within a set for `p`, there are, say, two groups (`G1` and `G2`, eventually to `Gn`) with again three values for a parameter q. `G1`, `G2` need to be displayed with the same `ColorFunction`.

How do I display this using `PairedBarChart`? I believe this is a nested list, but `PairedBarChart` only seems to take two (`x` and `y`) *m-by-n* (max number of dimensions = 2) matrices?

Appreciate your hints!

UPDATE: SAMPLE DATA BELOW and extra level added in description above.

Data should be interpreted as data left  = x, dataright = y. 
In both, there is three groups p1, p2, p3 each consisting of two lists (G1 and G2), which in turn each consist of {q1,q2,q3}.

```
dataleft = {{{22.1801, 30.9241, 27.3873}, {30.0898, 42.7793, 38.6847}, {81.5488, 164.131, 97.6132}}, {{28.5354, 30.1192, 26.7762}, {26.7111,27.5938, 25.8865}, {72.1467,91.9632, 53.7431}}};
dataright (*here identical to left, just for the idea*) = {{{22.1801, 30.9241, 27.3873},{30.0898, 42.7793, 38.6847}, {81.5488,164.131, 97.6132}}, {{28.5354, 30.1192, 26.7762}, {26.7111, 27.5938, 25.8865}, {72.1467, 91.9632, 53.7431}}};
```

Comment: You should provide a sample of the dataset.

Answer (score 2):

Given the nested structure of your data you should consider `ChartLayout -> Stacked`:

```
dataleft = {{{22.1801, 30.9241, 27.3873}, {30.0898, 42.7793, 
     38.6847}, {81.5488, 164.131, 97.6132}}, {{28.5354, 30.1192, 
     26.7762}, {26.7111, 27.5938, 25.8865}, {72.1467, 91.9632, 
     53.7431}}};

dataright = {{{22.1801, 30.9241, 27.3873}, {30.0898, 42.7793, 
    38.6847}, {81.5488, 164.131, 97.6132}}, {{28.5354, 30.1192, 
    26.7762}, {26.7111, 27.5938, 25.8865}, {72.1467, 91.9632, 
    53.7431}}};

s11 = dataleft[[1]];
s12 = dataleft[[2]];
s21 = dataright[[1]];
s22 = dataright[[2]];

labels = Reverse@Range@Length@s1;
```

**Left-Right**

```
s1 = Flatten[Transpose[{s11, s12}], 1];
s2 = Flatten[Transpose[{s21, s22}], 1] - 10;

PairedBarChart[s1, s2,
 AxesLabel -> "Nr.",
 ChartLabels -> {Placed[{"Left", "Right"}, Above], Placed[labels, "CenterAxis"], None},
 ChartLayout -> "Stacked",
 ChartLegends -> SwatchLegend[{"A", "B", "C"}]]
```

[image]

**First-Second**

```
p1 = Flatten[Transpose[{s11, s21 - 10}], 1];
p2 = Flatten[Transpose[{s12, s22 - 10}], 1];

PairedBarChart[p1, p2,
 AxesLabel -> "Nr.",
 ChartLabels -> {Placed[{"First", "Second"}, Above], Placed[labels, "CenterAxis"], None},
 ChartLayout -> "Stacked",
 ChartLegends -> SwatchLegend[{"A", "B", "C"}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but it's not what I'm looking for. I need to be able to read the values, so non-stacking is preferred. Moreover, I'd like to have e.g. Nr. 1 and 2 labeled p1, and then another label '1' (and '2') for the triplet (which is now stacked, but should be separated). Any ideas?